# WSADMIN: Invalid command "print"

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I'm trying to run a print commant using websphere **wsadmin** and it gives me the error " error while eval'ing Jacl expression:
invalid command name "print"", although the command is totally correct. As in the screenshot.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can be fixed by changing the default scripting language on the properties file

```
..\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\properties\wsadmin.properties
```

to be jython instead of jacl

```
com.ibm.ws.scripting.defaultLang=jython
```

Comment: You could also use the '-lang' option to specify the language. This will override com.ibm.ws.scripting.defaultLang property.
see: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=scripting-wsadmin-tool for more details